# VSCODE - MQL5 - Syntax Highlighting - Problems

Tags: visual-studio-code, mql5

I am trying to use VSCODE to edit my mql5 scripts.

in the attached screenshot - VSCODE prompts for 5 problems in the script.

These are false problems since the script compiles successfully.

I think that for some reason VSCODE thinks this is c++ code.

How can i eliminate these problems?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, use MetaEditor which is specifically designed to edit and compile MQL4/5.

Visual Studio does not support MQL4/5. It thinks you are using c++ because that is what it is meant to be used for, not MQL4/5.